# biblatex: names bold, et al. in italics

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biber

I want the names in my bibliography, as well as "et al." to be bold. However, I also want "et al." to be in italics. This does not seem to work. It works if I comment out everything under the comment that says `%%--names bold`. Funnily enough, it also works if I comment out the line `\babelfont{rm}{Garamond}` while keeping the authors bold. In the main text, italics work fine with Garamond.

UPDATE: Garamond simply doesn't offer bold italics. If anyone wants to do this, there is a way, which I laid out in my answer below.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=leveldown]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\babelprovide[main,import,language=Default]{english}
\babelprovide[import,language=Chinese Simplified]{chinese-simplified}


\babelfont{rm}{Garamond}
\babelfont{sf}{Gill Sans MT}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}{SimSun}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{sf}{SimSun}

%%%---bibliography
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
refsection=chapter,
style=numeric-comp,
giveninits=true,
maxbibnames=3,
date=year,
sorting=none,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    bibliography = {References},
}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}

%%-- et al. in italics
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    andothers = {\mkbibemph{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
}

%%---names bold
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname} 

%%--calling bib file
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Title of a chapter}

    It works with in-text \emph{italics}. But not when citing \fullcite{herrmann}

    \printbibliography  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Garamond does not offer a bold italics option. One could download the font Adobe Garamond bold italics from http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Adobe-Garamond-Bold-Italic and set it as the bold italics option by adding `\setmainfont[BoldItalicFont={AGaramond-Bolditalic}]{Garamond}` to the preamble. This, however, only works for monolingual documents.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=leveldown]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
BoldItalicFont={AGaramond-Bolditalic}
]{Garamond}     

%%%---bibliography
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
refsection=chapter,
style=numeric-comp,
giveninits=true,
maxbibnames=3,
date=year,
sorting=none,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    bibliography = {References},
}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}

%%-- et al. in italics
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    andothers = {\mkbibemph{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
}

%%---names bold
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname} 

%%--calling bib file
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title of a chapter}
It works with in-text \emph{italics} and with
\textbf{\emph{bold italics}}.
Also when citing \fullcite{herrmann}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```